# Unable to get OU structure to populate a comboBox

Tags: powershell, combobox, powershell-studio

I'm following along with a powershell tutorial [here](http://powershelltaskforce.com/2013/12/import-the-ad-module-and-comboboxes/).

I am unable to get the comboxBox to populate as they have in this example. 
Keeps passing a null item to the combobox helper method of PS Studio.

Im able to get a list of my orgs OUs, by name at a console with:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase 'OU=accounts,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=org' -SearchScope OneLevel -filter * | ft name
```

I cant wrap my head around translating this console query over to a combobox in studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `format-table` is returning a single multi-line string with embedded format codes and newlines, not objects.  If you want an array of the OU names for your combobox, trade that for `select-object` and use `-ExpandProperty` on the Name property:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase 'OU=accounts,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=org' -SearchScope OneLevel -filter * |
select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: thank you @mjolinor, you just saved me a ton of frustration today.  your suggestion worked perfectly.